# how to get last x facebook message + answer with php?

Tags: php, facebook

Is there a way to get my latest facebook message +comments to show on my own  website?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php), which provides API's for exactly the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has fairly well-documented developer resources; you can get started at http://developers.facebook.com/, which should lead you to a few options for what you want to do.  In the deeper integration stuff, PHP integration is pretty well-supported, so you should be able to find good information.

Once you've gotten a handle on the general structure of their API/Connect framework, the specific information you need is in their dev wiki documentation for [Message (FQL)](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Message_(FQL)).